# Kivy Button within Button

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Is there a way to place a button inside of an existing button in Kivy? I am trying to create a library of videos (as buttons that open a popup when pressed) that each have the option to delete the video/widget when an 'x' is pressed in the top corner. I am wondering if there is a way to stack buttons on top of each other or place on button inside of another?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FloatLayout` and adjust the `pos_hint` to place the buttons at your desired location.
You can read about it on the link below.

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.floatlayout.html